# How to interact with a java servlet running on glassfish with telnet?

Tags: java, debugging, http, servlets

I have a servlet hosted in the glassfish server. i want to communicate with it using telnet to understand what is going on behind the scenes when using html form get method.

What should i give in the Host field of the HTTP request?

```
Get /WebApplication1/NServlet HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```

If i want to send custom properties in the HTTP request as below, is it possible to extract their value using request.getAttribute() method.

```
Get /WebApplication1/NServlet HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Custom-Attribute: xyz
```

Another doubt is that is javax.servlet package not a part of java SE sdk. i had to install java ee to get it running.

Comment: Why do you want to use telnet, that's nuts.  If you want to understand what's going on then write a simple client using Python and httplib, alternatively the Apache HttpClient library will help you...

Comment: It's time to learn HTTP: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: I'm on the phone with a support rep at (large software company name redacted) who is asking me to do this exact same thing to prove my Tomcat server isn't misconfigured. So I'd say, it's not totally nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use HTTP for your protocol (as you've suggested in your comments), check out [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). As the name suggests, it's the client-side of the client/server HTTP implementation, and it should be relatively easy to determine what to set on the client side such that you see it on the server.

There's a great tutorial [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html). I would perhaps get a simple page working in the servlet first, and check it via the browser, and then implement the client side.

Answer (score 1):

The `Host` field is just the hostname part of the URL, e.g. `Host: google.com` for http://google.com/

`Custom-Attribute: xyz` would be exposed in the `HttpServletRequest` using `getHeader()`, not `getAttribute`().

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I don't there's enough information for anyone to answer you.  Tomcat/Jetty/etc are basically web servers that contain servlets (and therefore JSP/JSF/Wicket etc etc) processors for dynamically generating content.
So, what is it you're trying to figure out, and why?

Comment: I want to use HTTP protocol for my application. just as HTTP has content-length, host properties i plan to send configuration parameters to the server from my client. so i could do request.getParameter("parameter-name"); is it the right way to use http protocol for my application or should i send my configuration parameters in the content portion of http request.

Comment: So you're trying to configure and manage an application via http?  If it's a java application, there's JMX which can do it much easier.  If it's not.. HttpClient.
What you're trying to do sounds like doing it the hard way.